# How to get value from dynamic added edittext in JSONArray in android?

Tags: android, json, dynamic

I have created a layout, which contains multiple `EditText` and `TextView`. At the button click I am adding dynamically this layout in my `LinearLayout`. File name of this file is "`education_fields.xml`".

```
<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow4"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:paddingTop="5dp"
    >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/degreeNameAdd"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:text="@string/degree_name"
        android:layout_marginLeft="35dp"
        android:gravity="center|start"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"

        tools:ignore="RtlHardcoded" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/ratio4Add"
        android:text="@string/ratio_sign"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="20dp" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:id="@+id/degreeBoxAdd"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:ems="10"
        android:background="@drawable/edittext_default_bg"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:textCursorDrawable="@drawable/color_cursor"/>

</TableRow>
<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
    android:layout_below="@id/tableRow4"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:paddingTop="5dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/highestBranchAdd"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:text="@string/branch"
        android:layout_marginLeft="35dp"
        android:gravity="center|start"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"

        tools:ignore="RtlHardcoded" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/ratio1Add"
        android:text="@string/ratio_sign"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="20dp" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:id="@+id/branchBoxAdd"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:ems="10"
        android:background="@drawable/edittext_default_bg"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:textCursorDrawable="@drawable/color_cursor"/>

</TableRow>


<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="25dp"
    android:id="@+id/removeButton"
    android:background="@drawable/dotted_button"
    android:textSize="12sp"
    android:inputType="text"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tableRow1"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:textColor="#50000000"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/remove"
    android:text="REMOVE"
    />
```

In my java code, I am adding this layout after clicking at button.

My java code is here:

```
addField.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater =
    (LayoutInflater) getBaseContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
final View addView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.edutcation_fields, null);
EditText degreeNameBox = (EditText) addView.findViewById(R.id.degreeBoxAdd);
EditText branchBox = (EditText) addView.findViewById(R.id.branchBoxAdd);
allEds.add(degreeNameBox);
allEds.add(branchBox);
Button removeField = (Button) addView.findViewById(R.id.removeButton);
removeField.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        ((LinearLayout) addView.getParent()).removeView(addView);
    }
});
container.addView(addView);
}
```

If I click button 3 times, It's adding 3 layouts in my `LinearLayout` containter, means in each layout 2 `EditText` is there and total number of dynamic `EditText` is 6. If I fill up all the `EditText` and try to get value of each `EditText` using these code:

```
String[] strings = new String[allEds.size()];
for(int i=0; i < allEds.size(); i++) {
    strings[i] = allEds.get(i).getText().toString();
}
```

Then i am getting value in a array like this:

```
["jhon","23","robert","25","smith","36"]
```

But I want to get value like this:

```
[{"Name":jhon","Age":"23"},{"Name":"robert","Age":"25"},{"Name":"smith","Age":"36"}]
```

If this is not correct way, then please anyone provide me code for this problem.

Answer (score 0):

With your code you're loading the result in an array of Strings (`String[]`) not a Json array.

Assuming that you have always the **Name** at the *even indexes* and the **Age** at *odd indexes*, you can do something like that:

```
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();

for(int i=0; i < allEds.size()-1; i+=2) { // increment by 2, to move to the next pair
    JSONObject personObj = new JSONObject();

    try {
       String name = allEds.get(i).getText().toString();
       String age = allEds.get(i+1).getText().toString();
       personObj.put("Name", name);
       personObj.put("Age", age);

    } catch (JSONException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
    }

    jsonArray.put(personObj);
}
```